# Selecting the default GPU on an Asus motherboard

Tags: gpu

I have an ASUS P9X79 motherboard, on which I originally had one graphics card (a cheap nVidia GeForce 210). I recently bought a newer, better graphics card, and inserted it into the second PCI-E slot on the motherboard.

The new card is recognized by Linux but not by the BIOS - `lspci` and the nVidia control panel both show the 2 GPUs if I keep my monitors on the old one, but the monitors stay blank if I plug them into the new GPU.

I tried swapping both cards to see if the motherboard defaulted to the GPU on the first slot, with no avail : the video output stayed on the old GPU.

Is there a hardware switch or a hidden option in the BIOS setup menu that would let me change the default GPU?

Comment: It sounds like both cards are external.  Why don't you simply remove the previous card before shutting down the system, replace the card, but if the card isn't even seen by BIOS you have a larger problem.

Comment: That's probably what I am going to do. But I expected to be able to select the card I want since the mobo supports multiple ones...

Comment: You gain nothing from two seperate GPUs. Performance is only gained if you connect them by SLI which is possible based on the age the original card.

Comment: I may use OpenCL in the future, so I could gain something by having two separate GPUs. But yeah, in the meantime I'll remove the old card.